# How to select and write to external windows console using a java class

Tags: java, matlab, batch-file, apache-kafka

In Windows 10, several console applications are running and I need to select one particular console, perhaps by its title(?) and write or print to it using a java class.

Specific details: Start several bat files from the kafka folder (C:\Kafka_2.12-2.5.0\bin\windows), namely:

```
1. zookeeper-server-start.bat
2. kafka-server-start.bat
3. kafka-topics.bat               <------ to set topic
4. kafka-console-p:roducer.bat    <------ to post messages from java class
```

Using a java class in MATLAB, is it possible to produce kafka messages by writing to console no. 4 (kafka-console-producer)?

Comment: See AttachConsole https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/attachconsole

Comment: I need to use java, attachconsole() is only for C++

Comment: I'm sorry, it part of the core Windows API. Any language should be able to access it. I've used it in VB6 and VB.NET.

Comment: You could use the C module in MatLab to call the Windows API directly.

Answer (score 0):

So far I understand you want to send keystrokes to (one of) the console windows using a java application?
Then check out this class: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Robot.html

However I never used that class and do not know how to select which console window would receive the input.